# No launch button on newly installed application

Tags: software-installation

I have tried to install two applications, bluej and bracket. Both seemed to install fine in the software centre but when I try to open them (via the Ubuntu button) there is no launch button. Can anyone help?

Comment: Open the Application Launcher (Ubuntu button) and type `bracket`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all Ubuntu applications have graphical interface. Some of them are supposed to be used with command-line interface (CLI) in terminal.

CLI applications do not create graphical shortcuts aka "launch buttons".

Comment: Thanks for you quick feedback. I have just now typed in the application names and clicked on the icon. They have both now opened. I swear that didn't happen before.

Comment: @Sara202: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**